# Form input with type datetime not sending value as expected in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activeadmin, datetimepicker

We are using gem `active_admin` in our project for admin side. I am facing an issue in an active admin form. I have form input as type datetime.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Example do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :name, :label => "Serial"
      f.input :batteries_changed_at
    end
    f.buttons
   end
end
```

In the above code input `batteries_changed_at` is with data type datetime. Date time picker is coming as separate select box for year,month, date and time. So when we select a value from each dropdown and click on update button, values not getting properly in the backend. Instead of coming a single key as `batteries_changed_at` it is coming as parts like `batteries_changed_at(1i)` for year `batteries_changed_at(2i)` for month as so on. Example given below.

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/wQfcyXfM+vtJKY9OcyND3ARlA4YfNlHfFS1hCuNvMg=", "lockbox"=>{"name"=>"101973", "user_id"=>"2", "batteries_changed_at(1i)"=>"2019", "batteries_changed_at(2i)"=>"5", "batteries_changed_at(3i)"=>"6", "batteries_changed_at(4i)"=>"00", "batteries_changed_at(5i)"=>"23"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"10121"}
```

I have tried many ways like giving input like

```
f.input :batteries_changed_at, as: :datetime_picker
```

as suggested. Can anyone please help me to solve this. I want to get the value in single key `batteries_changed_at`. I am stuck because of this. Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the wiki to add datetime picker in activeadmin - https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/combine-datetime-picker-with-activeadmin

Comment: @apr did you able to setup datetime field in active admin using above blog??